# BigQuery Select columns associated with a max value when grouping by variable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table that sets up a one to many relationship between `id` and `value`.

The schema is as follows:

```
id      INTEGER NULLABLE    
day     NUMERIC NULLABLE    
value   NUMERIC NULLABLE
```

I would like to group by `id` and select the rows with the highest `value`. I want to be sure to also `SELECT` an additional column but I want to be sure it is from the same row as the maximum `value`:

```
SELECT id, ANY_VALUE(day), MAX(value) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Given the below possible records:

```
id day value
1   1    3
1   2    5
```

Can I be sure that my query will always return `day = 2` if `value = 5` is selected as the `MAX(value)`? Is it possible that `day` and `value` will ever comes from different records with the same `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't with that query.  Instead:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)].*
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY id;
```

You could also use a similar trick in your query but only for `day`:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(day ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)] as day,
       MAX(value) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error from BigQuery: `Dot-star is not supported for type ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, day NUMERIC, value NUMERIC>> at [1:8]`

Comment: After trying your edit, I have a new error: `Column id contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [3:10]`

Comment: After using your second recommendation (the lower one), I get this error `Array index 0 is out of bounds (underflow)`

Comment: @DylanRussell . . . Typo.  That should be `ORDINAL(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select as value array_agg(t order by value desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by id
```

Comment: What does OFFSET do here?

Comment: good question :o) - array with one element (because of limit 1) is still an array. so to extract that element - you use `[offset(0)]`

Answer (score 0):

is this of any help to you ?

```
select id , day , (max(value2) over (partition by id)) valuemax from myTable;
```